# Whats the easiest way to sync Outlook with Gmail?

Tags: sync

I found gSyncIt to be a bit complicated.
Binary has too many options  so I get a bit lost.
So far EVO Collaborator was very easy to setup, but its not build on Google's API so its not very compatible with task synchronisation and its limited to 1 address book.

Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

just found your question. I have been browsing for solution last week as well. Gsyinit was one of them, and it is complicated indeed. I found a better solution - Sync2, it is a very convenient and useful software with a number of cool features. I would also like to mention their support team, as it is truly amazing.